# iPhone UIDatePicker style

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there any way/trick to change the size, font, background color etc. of a uiDatePicker?? even the backgroundcolor attribute does not work and the default style of the picker is sooo irrelevant with the design of my application :(

Comment: objective-c, for iphone programming

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use a UIPickerView instead?  I've seen people use images as backgrounds using this.  You'll have to code up all the date logic though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way.  Even if there is, your app will likely get rejected for doing it.