# How to change Font of UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone

I have used UIDatePicker in my app. I want to (actually have to) change the font size (as my app needs) and font family in that datepicker.

Please help, if any body has done that before...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [iPhone UIDatePicker style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676549/iphone-uidatepicker-style)

Based on that link, it doesn't look good...

You are most likely going to have to create a custom picker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't advocate doing this, but if you really need to resize the font, just resize the entire UIDatePicker.

```
datePicker.transform = .init(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
```