# Custom font in iOS7 UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview, uidatepicker

According to previously asked questions [(this one for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676549/iphone-uidatepicker-style), there is no way of adjusting the font attributes of a `UIDatePicker`. Has anyone discovered in iOS7 any new ways to do this?

I would otherwise recreate the `UIDatePicker` with a `UIPickerView`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Apple's UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3), we are not allowed to customize date pickers.

But all is not lost, I've seen other StackOverflow answers for similar questions that [suggest making a fake UIDatePicker using UIPickerView and customizing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance).

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'd agree, this appears to be the only option.

Comment: Why, just why do Apple do things like this?  I've customised the text in a UIPicker with one short line of code.  I'm guessing it has something to do with internationalisation ... dates ... I love dates ... not.